# EF Code First Entity Mapping with Foreign Key in Mapped Entity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-annotations

[image: Demo Model]
<sub>(source: [mcainsh.info](http://mcainsh.info/soimages/efkeyissue2.jpg))</sub>

The tables are just for an example, what I am trying to do is map a virtual Manufacturer in the Book entity. I've tried using data annotation similar to below:

```
[ForeignKey("PublisherId")]
public virtual Publisher { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Publisher.ManufacturerCompanyId")]
[InverseProperty("ManufacturerId")]
public virtual Manufacturer { get; set; }
```

Is this something that can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You're configuring incorrectly the foreign keys. To do what you want, your model should be like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public int PublisherId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PublisherId")]
    public virtual Publisher Publisher{ get; set; }

    public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ManufacturerId")]
    public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
}

public class Manufacturer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Publisher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books  { get; set; }
}
```

In this model you have two one-to-many relationships, the first between `Book` and `Publisher` and the second one between `Book` and `Manufacturer`. As you can see in the `Book` class, if you want to use a FK property you must declare a property of the same type of the PK of the related entity (see `PublisherId` and `ManufacturerId`).Now, you can apply the `ForeignKey` annotation to the navigation property and tell it which property is the foreign key for the relationship, as I show above. Alternatively, you can add`ForeignKey` attribute to the `ManufacturerId`, along with information telling it which navigation property represents the relationship it is a foreign key for:

```
  [ForeignKey("Manufacturer")]
  public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
  public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
```

If you want, you don't need to create the FKs properties, EF will do the job for you begin the escene. It will create a FK row in your `Books` table for each relationship (check the DB after execute your code):

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    //public int PublisherId { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("PublisherId")]
    public virtual Publisher Publisher{ get; set; }

    //public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("ManufacturerId")]
    public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The sample I provided was a basic illustration of the problem I have. I'm working on inherited code and trying to avoid changing the existing structure if possible. I take it that it isn't possible to do what I was trying?

Comment: No, I'm afraid that is not possible, the three options that I show in my answer are all the possibilities that you have

Comment: Hello @wmcainsh, if you thing that my answer was useful and it help you to understand better how work the FKs in EF, please, could mark your question as answered